# How to implement debounceTime the Angular way

Tags: angular

I'm implementing `debounceTime` in an autocomplete scenario.

I want to use the `debounceTime` to limit the number of calls to the server. Google gives me 3 potential solutions, for which I pasted the code below.

All of them however, seem to have some drawbacks in my opinion, so I am looking for the most "Angular" way of implementing it.

1. ```js
   fromEvent(document.getElementById('myelement'), 'mouseover').pipe(
      debounceTime(1000),
      map(data => data.srcElement)
   ).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
   ```

This strikes me as "non-Anular'ish" as the component has a reference to element ID's in the HTML. This creates a dependency from the class to the HTML, in which I already have on the other way around. And it looks like plain JS in stead of "Angular'ish".

2. ```js
   this.bookId.valueChanges.pipe(
     debounceTime(1000),
     switchMap(id => {
       console.log(id);
       return this.bookService.getBook(id);
     })
   ).subscribe(res => this.book = res);
   ```

This one looked the most "Anular'ish", with a subscription on the data-property in the class (`bookId`), but it needs reactive forms as I understand, which we do not use (not against it, so this is a possibility for us).

3. ```js
   this.subject
     .pipe(debounceTime(500))
     .subscribe(() => {
       this.formGroup.controls.name.setValidators([ Validators.minLength(5) ]);
       this.formGroup.controls.name.updateValueAndValidity();
     });

   onKeyUp(): void {
     this.subject.next();
   }
   ```

   ```html
    <input type="text" formControlName="name" (keyup)="onKeyUp()">
   ```

   This also doesn't look very "Angular'ish" because it looks like plain JavaScript that I catch and process DOM events. I thought that, in my opinion, this is not an Angular way of working?

Comment: The reason I ask is that we are not so very familiair with Angular and we would like the app as 'standard' as possible for new colleagues to come.

Comment: Options 2 and 3 are both fine.

Comment: Michel, personally I'll take the second aproach, but use a simple formControl, declare `myControl=new FormControl()` and use `<input [formControl]="myControl">`. It's not necesary create a formGroup nor a form

Answer (score 1):

Options 2 and 3 look Angular'ish.
However, you can make option 1 also angularish.

Angular has a concept of ViewChild to get DOM elements into component class. You can use Angular's ngAfterViewInit life-cycle hook to get the DOM element. One way would be this:

```
@ViewChild ('myName', { static: false }) myName;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.myName.nativeElement, 'mouseover').pipe(debounceTime(1000), 
    tap(data => console.log(data)),
    map(data => data.srcElement)
    ).subscribe(val => console.log(val)); 
  }
```

You can see this stackblitz for more details:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fotgbf